# echo `/usr/sbin/service postfix status`; lists files in folder and appends postfix status

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04

I'm getting a strange behaviour from bash which I can't find a solution to.

My 2 line script (in my user home folder)

```
#!/bin/bash  
echo `/usr/sbin/service postfix status`;
```

Produces a list of files in the folder, and at the end, appends `postfix is running`:

```
aptupdate.txt aptUpdate.txt ca checksite.sh cronlist.sh customers defrag_DB.sh downloads firewall_rules.txt groupmembers.sh joomla.int.vhost mail mem_usage.py mysqltuner.pl old_watchdog.sh phpinfo.php processlist.txt test.py tuning-primer.sh watchdog.sh postfix is running
```

I've tried a number of combinations.  If I don't specify a service, the echoed output is the usage for the service command.  If I specify a service but not a verb following it, the usage for the service is echoed  (ie restart|stop|start|status).

When I run the same command in the terminal, I get `* postfix is running`.

**edit**
I believe the leading asterisks is causing the files to be listed.

Comment: `echo \`/usr/sbin/service postfix status\`;` should probably be just `/usr/sbin/service postfix status`. What's the reason for using `echo`?

Comment: this is in a script.  postfix will be replaced with a variable so I can check on various services.  Instead of echo, the output will go into a variable.  What I've shown here is the 'bug' I'm trying to sort out.

Comment: Still no reason to use `echo`; just use `/usr/sbin/service "${variable}" status`. And the so called bug is that the whitespace returned from `/usr/sbin/service postfix status` isn't quoted and thus `echo` will turn them into single spaces.

Comment: it will become  `sStatus=$(/usr/sbin/service $variable status)`;  then I will use a `=~` regex check to determine if I need to start it up or not.

Comment: So... no `echo`, then? Don't forget to quote your variables! BTW, would `/usr/sbin/service "$variable" start` really hurt? I'm pretty sure it'll just not do anything if the service is already running.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind.  I'm new to bash scripting, so I'm looking at various examples along the way.  What I'm puzzled about is why the list of files is showing up when I state the full command????

Comment: I want the script to send me a mail if the service is down as the server is remotely located.  To keep a record and have a chance to investigate.

Comment: If that is your script verbatim, then I can't see why that would happen (unless `/usr/sbin/service postfix status` itself is doing it). How do you run the script?

Comment: yes, that's it.  I run it from my home folder using `./watchdog.sh`  Later, I will be able to specify a service as a parameter.  When I run the same command in the terminal window, it just outputs `* postfix is running`.   (!!  I go it.  The leading asterisks is causing the directory listing.)

Comment: Ah! There it is. The asterisk in the output is unquoted and thus Bash expands it before handing to `echo`. So the (useless) use of `echo` is actually causing the problem (in combination with poor quoting).

Comment: And there's no need for `grep`, just learn to quote things: `echo "$(/usr/sbin/service postfix status)"` (Note how I changed the deprecated backticks syntax to `$()` and removed the unnecessary semicolon.) Or just don't do it like that in the first place!

Comment: Ok, didn't know the backticks are depricated.  The $() format makes much more sense. That did the trick :)  THANKS.  Post the last suggestion and I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
echo `/usr/sbin/service postfix status`;
```

has a few problems. Besides the deprecated backticks syntax and the unnecessary semicolon, neither of which hurt, other than ones eyes, the biggest problem is the lack of quotes.

If `/usr/sbin/service postfix status` prints `* postfix is running` then the line will ‘turn into’:

```
echo * postfix is running
```

And then Bash does its thing and expands that asterisk into the names of all the files in the current directory (if any exist).

The quick fix is adding some quotes:

```
echo "`/usr/sbin/service postfix status`";
```

Or in a more cleaned-up version:

```
echo "$(/usr/sbin/service postfix status)"
```

This however means execute one thing, take what it prints to STDOUT and hand it to `echo`, so that `echo` can print it to STDOUT. In other words; `echo` isn't providing anything. Once take it out we're left with:

```
/usr/sbin/service postfix status
```

I.e. no need for `$()` since we just want to run a command, and no need for quotes since the results of the command won't be used for anything (they'll go straight to STDOUT).

---

When writing shell scripts I recommend the following:

- `set -x` to see what is being executed. In this case it could have helped to see the asterisk being expanded. If this is too verbose for production it can be removed once everything is working.
- `set -e` so that a failed command at one stage won't mess up the execution of later commands. This one's probably good to have in production as well.
- `set -u` if you are <del>paranoid</del> *concerned* (and you know what you're doing).
- http://www.shellcheck.net Either now and then online, or as a plugin in your text editor.